# How do I access individual fields of a form in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, hiccup

I'm building my very first web app, and I am having a hard time accessing individual fields of a form when the user `submit`s the form. Here's what I have:

```
(defroutes app
  (GET "/" [] homepage)
  (POST "/city" request display-city)
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))


(defn display-city [request]
  (html5
     [:div {:class "the-city"}
      [:h2 "ALL ABOUT YOUR CITY"]
      [:ul
       [:li "Your city is " (str request) "! That's all"]]]))

;; and here's the hiccup form:
   [:form {:action "/city" :method "post"}
    (anti-forgery-field)
    [:p "Enter your home address"]
    [:div
     [:label {:for "street-field"} "Street:"]
     [:input {:id "street-field"
              :type "text"
              :name "street"}]]
    [:div
     [:label {:for "city-field"} "City:"]
     [:input {:id "city-field"
              :type "text"
              :name "city"}]
    [:div
     [:label {:for "state-field"} "State:"]
     [:input {:id "state-field"
              :type "text"
              :name "state"}]
     [:label {:for "zip-field"} "ZIP:"]
     [:input {:id "zip-field"
              :type "text"
              :name "zip"
              :size "10"}]]
    [:div.button
     [:button {:type "submit"} "Submit"]]]])
```

;; When I run the code above, I can see the entire form that's submitted via `(str request)`, in what looks to be a Clojure map. But I can't figure out how to extract individual "key/vals" (from that address form, I'd like to extract the city), or how to store those results in a way that I can use it.  Any ideas?

This is a super basic `/city` page that I am trying to get running to understand how things work before building bigger things.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is "city"? Pls show an example of input data, output data, what you've tried, & what happened.

Answer (score 4):

In your `request` map, there should be a key `:form-params` with a map of key/value pairs that were POSTed. Here's how you could get an individual value out:

```
(get-in request [:form-params :city])
```

Or you could destructure `:form-params` map to bind many values at once:

```
(let [{:keys [city state zip]} (:form-params request)]
  (format "%s, %s %s" city state zip))
```

Comment: Thank you! When I use the `(get-in)` form, it's telling me that it is: `Unable to resolve symbol: param-city in this context`

within a `let` clause.  Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

(let [param-city (get-in request [:form-params :city]
                          .....)]

Comment: hmm it's returning an empty string, would you know what could cause that?